# Calling previous input value using JavaScript, showing that value in another div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one html page that is divided in multiple section I'm trying to take input from one div tag and trying to show that in another div tag how can we access that value using JavaScript and can show it in another division tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>


    ----css---  
    <style type='text/css'> 
        span { 
            text-decoration:none;
            color:blue;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .page {
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>

    ---javascript----

    <script> //javascript
    // show the given page, hide the rest
    function show(elementID) {
        // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
        var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
        if (!ele) {
            alert("no such element");
            return;
        }

        // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
        var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
        for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            pages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

        // then show the requested page
        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    ---body---
    <body>
        <div class="page" id="page0">
            <h1>Heloo</h1>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" id="u_name" name="uname" placeholder="suchit"/>
          </form>
          <span onclick="show('page1');"><input type="button" value="submit"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page1" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p id="user_name">content of page</p>
            <span onclick="show('page2');">2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page2" style="display:none;">
            <p>content of page</p>
            <span onclick="show('page3');">3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="page" id="page3" style="display:none;">
            <p>content of page</p>
        </div>

    ---javascript---
    <script type="text/javascript"> //javascript
          var x= document.getElementById('u_name').value;  
              document.getElementById('user_name').innerHTML=x;
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your field name as well.

```
                function show(elementID,previousTag) {
                    // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
                    var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
                    if (!ele) {
                        alert("no such element");
                        return;
                    }

                    // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
                    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
                    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                        pages[i].style.display = 'none';
                    }

                    // then show the requested page
                    ele.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('span_'+elementID).innerHTML=document.getElementById(previousTag).innerHTML;
                }
            </script>
```

In this, we can pass element and PreviousTag name, which will be like Show

```
<span onclick="show('page1','u_name');"><input type="button" value="submit"/></span>
```

let me know if that helps. thanks

Comment: tried to reply on comment, but didn't post properly, please check my other reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code
I tried below one, which worked fine for me.. can you cross check please.

```
<script> //javascript
                    // show the given page, hide the rest
                    function show(elementID,previousTag) {
                        // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
                        var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
                        if (!ele) {
                            alert("no such element");
                            return;
                        }

                        // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
                        var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
                        for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
                            pages[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }

                        // then show the requested page
                        ele.style.display = 'block';
                        if(document.getElementById(previousTag).value ==null)
                        {
                        document.getElementById('span_'+elementID).innerHTML=document.getElementById(previousTag).innerText;
                        }else
                        {
                        document.getElementById('span_'+elementID).innerHTML=document.getElementById(previousTag).value;
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```